# Simple Cognito User Authentication With Code Grant Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a simple static website that uses AWS Cognito to authenticate users. That means I'm not using any advanced libraries but basing my code on the AWS example [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/master/sample/index.html).

If I use the default 'token' flow then the example works for my domain. However, as recommended by Amazon themselves in several places e.g. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-app-integration.html) I want to used 'code grant' flow, and as state in the example above I just uncomment line 221:

```
auth.useCodeGrantFlow();
```

However this fails causing the `onFailure` function to be called although oddly I do see the URL bar containing `code=xxxxx`. It appears there are more steps I need to do but all examples I find demonstrate the less favourable 'token flow'.

This is my specific `index.html` based on the above example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Cognito Auth JS SDK Sample</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styleSheetStart.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/amazon-cognito-auth.min.js"></script>
    <!-- To enable the advanced security feature -->
    <!-- <script src="https://amazon-cognito-assets.<region>.amazoncognito.com/amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js"> 
    </script> -->
    <!-- E.g. -->
    <!-- <script src="https://amazon-cognito-assets.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js"> 
    </script> -->
</head>

<body  onload="onLoad()">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/" target="_blank"
       title="Go to AWS Cognito Console">Cognito Console</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html"
       target="_blank" title="See Cognito developer docs">Docs</a> 
     </li>
    </ul>

    <h1>
        <a href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/MobileServices_AmazonCognito.png" alt="Amazon Cognito" title="Amazon Cognito"
       style="width:144px;height:144px;"></a><br>
    Amazon Cognito Auth Demo
    </h1>
    <!--removed for brevity -->
   <div><br></div>
   <div>
       <p id="statusNotAuth" title="Status">
          Sign-In to Continue
       </p>
       <p id="statusAuth" title="Status">
          You have Signed-In
       </p>
   </div>

<div class="tabsWell">
    <div id="startButtons">
        <div class="button">
            <a class="nav-tabs" id="signInButton" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Sign in">Sign In</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="userdetails">
            <p class="text-icon" title="Minimize" id="tabIcon" onclick="toggleTab('usertab');">_</p>
            <br>
            <h2 id="usertabtitle">Tokens</h2>
            <div class="user-form" id="usertab">
                <pre id="idtoken"> ... </pre>
      <pre id="acctoken"> ... </pre>
      <pre id="reftoken"> ... </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

// Operations when the web page is loaded.
function onLoad() {
    var i, items, tabs;
    items = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pane");
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("statusNotAuth").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("statusAuth").style.display = 'none';
    // Initiatlize CognitoAuth object
    var auth = initCognitoSDK();
    document.getElementById("signInButton").addEventListener("click", 
function() {
        userButton(auth);
    });
    var curUrl = window.location.href;
    auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(curUrl);
}

// Operation when tab is closed.
function closeTab(tabName) {
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'none';
}

// Operation when tab is opened.
function openTab(tabName) {
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
}

// Operations about toggle tab.
function toggleTab(tabName) {
    if (document.getElementById("usertab").style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById("usertab").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("tabIcon").innerHTML = '_';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("usertab").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("tabIcon").innerHTML = '+';
    }
}

// Operations when showing message.
function showMessage(msgTitle, msgText, msgDetail) {
    var msgTab = document.getElementById('message');
    document.getElementById('messageTitle').innerHTML = msgTitle;
    document.getElementById('messageText').innerHTML = msgText;
    document.getElementById('messageDetail').innerHTML = msgDetail;
    msgTab.style.display = "block";
}

// Perform user operations.
function userButton(auth) {
    var state = document.getElementById('signInButton').innerHTML;
    if (state === "Sign Out") {
        document.getElementById("signInButton").innerHTML = "Sign In";
        auth.signOut();
        showSignedOut();
    } else {
        auth.getSession();
    }
}

// Operations when signed in.
function showSignedIn(session) {
    document.getElementById("statusNotAuth").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("statusAuth").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("signInButton").innerHTML = "Sign Out";
    /* Removed for brevity */
    openTab("userdetails");
}

// Operations when signed out.
function showSignedOut() {
    document.getElementById("statusNotAuth").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("statusAuth").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('idtoken').innerHTML = " ... ";
    document.getElementById('acctoken').innerHTML = " ... ";
    document.getElementById('reftoken').innerHTML = " ... ";
    closeTab("userdetails");
}

// Initialize a cognito auth object.
function initCognitoSDK() {
    var authData = {
        ClientId : '<Removed>', // Your client id here
        AppWebDomain : '<Removed>', // Exclude the "https://" part.
        TokenScopesArray : [<removed>], // like ['openid','email','phone']...
        RedirectUriSignIn : '<domain removed>/index.html',
        RedirectUriSignOut : '<domain removed>/index.html'
    };
    var auth = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoAuth(authData);
    // You can also set state parameter - do I need to set this?
    auth.setState('ABCDXYZ');
    auth.userhandler = {
        onSuccess: function(result) {
            alert("Sign in success");
            showSignedIn(result);
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert("Error!" + err);
        }
    };
    // The default response_type is "token", uncomment the next line will make it be "code".
    auth.useCodeGrantFlow();
    return auth;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In dev tools I do see a call to `https://<domain-name-removed>/oauth2/token` but looks like it comes back with a 400 error.The response text is `"error":"invalid_client"`.

Is there some additional configuration I need to do, or as suggested in the AWS docs for authorisation code grant flow I need to implement additional BE code? I feel the example code is lacking a full description for code grant flow.
According to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I created the the app client for the user pool I created it with a secret key. This key must be returned in the header as part of the authentication process which I wasn't doing; the aws example doesn't indicate how this is achieved. Instead [direction is given](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/52#issuecomment-350115801) to create the app client *without* an app secret key

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly you should not use an app client secret for this. The AWS example is indeed correct, the [*code*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) you get in the url is meant to be used in another request in the process of acquiring the real *code* aka [*access_token*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4).